# exception: Row too big to fit into CursorWindow

Tags: flutter, sqflite

Soy nuevo en flutter y tengo este problema al momento de seleccionar todos los registros en una base de datos..

Cabe mencionar que la base de datos ya tiene registros

Se produjo una excepción. SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(Row too big to fit into CursorWindow requiredPos=1, totalRows=2) sql 'SELECT * FROM Tips' args []})

Tengo la clase DataTips este metodo el cual hace la consulta de todos los registros

```
Future<List<ClassTips>>getAllTips() async {
    final db = await database;
    var response = await db.query("Tips");
    List<ClassTips> list = response.map((c)=> ClassTips.fromMap(c)).toList();
    return list;
  }
```

Mi modelo de datos

```
class ClassTips {
  int id;
  String titulo;
  String descripcion;
  String complejidad;
  String lenguaje;
  String imagen;
  int logic;
...
```

Codigo donde mando a llamar el metodo

```
Widget _data(){
    return FutureBuilder<List<ClassTips>>(
      future: DataTips.db.getAllTips(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<ClassTips>> snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          return ListView.builder(
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
              ClassTips item = snapshot.data[index];
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: _cardTipo3(item),
              );
            }
          );
        }else{ Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator()); }
      }
    );
  }

 Widget _cardTipo3(ClassTips item){
    return Container(
      height: 280,
      width: 400,
      child: Stack(...//El stack contine distintos container[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
```

Comment: podrías indicar de que tamaño es tu base de datos ?

Comment: también que plugin estás usando?

Answer (score 0):

En el `else` te faltó la palabra `return`

Cambia esto :

```
}else{ Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator()); }
```

Por esto :

```dart
}else{ 
   return Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator()); 
}
```

Comment: Sigue ando la excepcion: Se produjo una excepción.
SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(Row too big to fit into CursorWindow requiredPos=1, totalRows=2) sql 'SELECT * FROM Tips' args []})

Comment: puedes actualizar la pregunta con el nuevo error que te sale?  si revisas el log de error inicial te dice que no estabas retornando ningún widget